How can I get QML Component size in RowLayout dynamically?
I try to get width of component inside the RowLayout. When component is completed I get 0. When I try to resize window size, I get this width correctly. Why? How can I get this size after running this app?
App output:
qml: onCompleted: rectangle width is 0
qml: onWidthChanged: rectangle width is 300
qml: onWidthChanged: rectangle width is 301
qml: onWidthChanged: rectangle width is 302
qml: onWidthChanged: rectangle width is 305
qml: onWidthChanged: rectangle width is 306
qml: onWidthChanged: rectangle width is 307

App.qml
import QtQuick 6.2

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Screen01 {
        id: mainScreen
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    onWidthChanged: {
        console.log("onWidthChanged: rectangle width is " + mainScreen.rectangle2.width)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("onCompleted: rectangle width is " + mainScreen.rectangle2.width)
    }

}

Screen01.ui.qml
import QtQuick 6.2
import QtQuick.Layouts

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle

    property alias rectangle2: rectangle2

    RowLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "yellow"
        }
    }
}


I connected to signal widthChanged of Rectangle object:
App.qml
Window {
//... 

    Screen01 {
        id: mainScreen
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Connections{
        target: mainScreen.rectangle2
        onWidthChanged: {
            console.log("rectangle width is " + mainScreen.rectangle2.width)
        }
    }
}


You can declare a new signal, say, info and use this to broadcast changes. Also, the onWidthChanged on the inner Rectangle is late enough to receive a non-zero value,
// Screen01.ui.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    signal info()
    property alias rectangle2: rectangle2
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "red"
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "yellow"
            onWidthChanged: Qt.callLater(info)
            onHeightChanged: Qt.callLater(info)
        }
    }
}

You can Try it Online!

This is because the RowLayout dimensions have not yet been fully calculated in the Component.onCompleted task. Getting the width before this is complete will return 0.
I recommend adding some waiting time before the data is retrieved. You can use Timer
Window {
    width: 600
        height: 400
        visible: true

        Screen01 {
            id: mainScreen
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Timer {
                id: widthCheckTimer
                interval: 100
                running: true
                repeat: false
                onTriggered: console.log("onCompleted (timer): rectangle width is " + mainScreen.rectangle2.width)
                }

        onWidthChanged: console.log("onWidthChanged: rectangle width is " + mainScreen.rectangle2.width)
        Component.onCompleted: widthCheckTimer.start()
}


output:
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qml: onCompleted (timer): rectangle width is 300

